# Concise / idiomatic replacement for a For loop

Tags: machine-learning, idiomatic-usage

I am using the following For loop to measure the misclassification errors in a Classifier.

```
errors = 0;
For[i = 1, i < Length[data], i++,
 actual = data[i][2];
 predicted = classifier[data[i]];
 If[actual != predicted, errors++]
 ]
Print[errors]
```

Is there a more concise / idiomatic replace instead of this For loop in Mathematica?

Comment: Is data a `List` or an `Association`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the data is a list, you can map elements of data and compare using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). Then, use [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html) to count `errors`.

```
classifier = Mod[#[[1]], 3] &;
data = {#, Mod[#, 2]} & /@ Range[20];

Count[(#[[2]] != classifier[#]) & /@ data, True]

  (*  13  *)
```

Or using [`CountsBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountsBy.html):

```
data // CountsBy[#[[2]] == classifier[#] &]

False /. %

  (*  <|True -> 7, False -> 13|>  *)

  (*   13                         *)
```

Comment: I made an extension to your answer and included a stand-alone example.  If you do not like this please revert the edit, and I shall post separately.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm okay. Thank you for adding an extension.

Comment: I misunderstand someting maybe.Look [here](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-19-13-21-50.png).

Comment: @yode The for loop condition is i < `Length[data]`

Answer (score 1):

If `classifier` was made with `Classify` we can use [`ClassifierMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurements.html) to find out the success rates.

Here is code following the example in [the previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138118/34008):

```
classifier = Mod[#[[1]], 3] &;
data = {#, Mod[#, 2]} & /@ Range[20];

cf = Classify[Rule @@@ data];

cm = ClassifierMeasurements[cf, Rule @@@ data]

cm["Recall"]

(* <|0 -> 0.3, 1 -> 0.1|> *)

cm["Precision"]

(* <|0 -> 0.25, 1 -> 0.125|> *)

cm["ConfusionMatrix"]

(* {{3, 7, 0}, {9, 1, 0}} *)
```